# shiny: dynamically change tab names

Tags: r, shiny, translation, navbar, tabpanel

I'm working on a Shiny application that is supposed to handle multiple languages. I managed to dynamically translate almost all elements of the app depending on a `selectInput` to choose the language. However the "hard stuff" remains the `navbarPage` tabs as well as the `tabPanels` inside my pages. I cannot change their names.  I tried this, but it does not work:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage("App Title",
                 tabPanel("tab1", 
                          selectInput("language", "language", c("EN", "FR"), width = '300px'),
                          textOutput("text")),
                 uiOutput("render_tab2"))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text = renderText({ switch(input$language, "EN"="hello world", "FR"="bonjour monde")  })
  output$render_tab2 = renderUI({
    tabPanel( title=switch(input$language, "EN"="tab2", "FR"="onglet2") )})}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And the `updatenavbarpanel()` family of functions are just to set the active tab, not change their characteristics...Is there a way to do it, if possible that does not change the structure of all my app... THanks a lot.

Comment: Check out [renderUI](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) to dynamically render the tabs with different names

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This piece of code set the title dynamically :

```
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage("App Title",
                 tabPanel(title = uiOutput("title_panel"), 
                          selectInput("language", "language", c("EN", "FR"), width = '300px')
                )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$title_panel = renderText({
        switch(input$language, "EN"="hello world", "FR"="bonjour monde") 
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit : Works with both `uiOutput("title_panel")` & `textOutput("title_panel")`

Comment: thanks! That's a great solution i haven't thought of !